# C# 2010 Child form not showing inside MDI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm trying to open child form inside MDI Form it's not working in visual studio 2010. I've written following code.

```
private void dashboardToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){        
 Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();
 dash.MdiParent = this;
 dash.Show();            
}
```

it shows Error : Form cannot be both an MDI child and MDI parent.
Parameter name: value. Then After I've tried this code.

```
private void dashboardToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){        
 Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();
 dash.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
 dash.Show();            
}
```

This is working but only issue my child form opens at the top and MDI Hide back side. Can any one tell me what exactly issue?

Comment: Not related but please note that starting with Visual Studio 2015 Microsoft provides essentially the functionality of Visual Studio Professional free of charge as Visual Studio Community. The express versions of Visual Studio should be abandoned.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the second point ? A screenshot could be helpful !